# fscanf results in a segmentation fault

Tags: c

```
void RdImage(FILE *fpi, char Image1[MAXROW][MAXCOL], int Nrows, int Ncols) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, temp;

    while (!feof(fpi)) {
        if (i % Nrows == 0) {
            i = 0; 
            j++;
        }

        **fscanf(fpi, "%d", temp);**     

        if (temp == 1) {
            Image1[i][j] == AP;
        } else {
            Image1[i][j] == PL;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

The line I've inclosed in asterisks is giving me a segmentation fault. The file is definitely NOT empty. I've used the same line twice elsewhere in my program and it doesn't behave this way there.

Comment: The two lines with `Image1[i][j] == ` are no-ops (except they could possibly be undefined behavior). Please always check the return codes of I/O functions so you at least have a clue if they're working or not.

Comment: You really don't want to use `while (!feof(whatever))` -- ever. In this case, it looks like you really want something closer to `while (1==fscanf(fpi, "%d", &temp)) {` (and obviously remove the call to `fscanf` inside the loop).

Answer (score 7):

`temp` is an integer; you have to pass its address:

```
fscanf(fpi, "%d", &temp);
```

Turn on warnings in your compiler to catch bugs like this.

Comment: Oh wow do I feel stupid: straight from the compiler at the bottom of the screen:/A1ImageScale.c:210: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int*', but argument 3 has type 'int'

Comment: Yep, that's what warnings are for! Lots of programmers just ignore them -- warnings are really useful in many cases, if you understand what they are saying :)

Comment: Those ignoring warnings because they do not understand them, I would call students ... @nneonneo

Answer (score 1):

As per C99 Std

**7.19.6.2 The fscanf function**

**%d** 
Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as
expected for the subject sequence of the strtol function with the value 10
for the base argument.

```
The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer.
```

so

```
fscanf(fpi, "%d", &temp); //Here Address of temp is passed.
```

is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

please use &temp instead of temp in fscanf

fscanf(fpi, "%d", &temp);

Comment: You're probably right, but don't just say "please try it" without some kind of explanation...